# Reinstall Mountain Lion after factory reset to Lion

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I have a MBP Early 2011 which came with Lion. I purchased Mountain Lion from the App Store and installed it, and it worked fine for awhile. Recently my machine crapped out and my disk was corrupted pretty bad, and I had to reset to factory settings, so I'm on Lion again.

When I go to the App Store, Mountain Lion is there, but it wants me to pay the 20 bucks again. I originally bought it from the App Store, so I would have thought it would have remembered me, but I guess not.

Is there any way to get it back, short of contacting Apple for support?

Comment: After installing the Mountain Lion, how did you "factory reset" to Lion?

Comment: @Buscar The disk contents were pretty much hosed - it was split to Mac and Windows with Bootcamp - the Bootcamp partition booted but gave me fatal Windows errors, and the Mac partition wouldn't even boot. I couldn't even wipe the disk using the disk utility, since it told me it couldn't unmount the disk. I put a different HDD in the machine, booted to that, plugged my disk in to the USB slot and wiped it using the disk utilities, then put the disk back in and booted to the disk utilities, reformatted, repartitioned, and reinstalled from the recovery "disk".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From Personal Experience:** I believe it's the same for everyone. It is the only item in the Mac App Store that doesn't show purchased even though it is purchased, even in UK, however I don't think they would make you pay for it again as it is linked to your account. You could call them and ask them or ask a Genius in store, I would just to be sure you don't get billed again for it, even though you shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks - it was showing $19.99 and "Buy Now" on Mountain Lion, but apparently I wasn't logged in to the App Store at the time. I logged in manually from the "Store" menu, and once logged in, the link changed to "Download", and allowed me to download without paying again.

Answer (score 1):

When you run App Store and go to Purchases, is OS X Mountain Lion listed at all? If so, what's its status?

If not, it sounds like you'll need to contact Apple Support. When you purchased Mountain Lion, they emailed you a receipt that includes the order id number and date of purchase, so getting this straightened out with them should be easy.

Note: The email sender is iTunes Store, not App Store, and the subject will include only a receipt number, not "Mountain Lion receipt" or the like. Search your email for "OS X Mountain Lion" and you should find it straightaway.

If you deleted that email, and the App Store doesn't list Mountain Lion as purchased, you might be out of luck. Contacting Apple in this case is unavoidable. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, Apple does preserve your purchase of Mountain Lion in the App Store. In face, I'm pretty sure that you can install it on multiple machines with one account. If you purchased it successfully, it should be there. I would definitely contact Apple; there's no need to pay again.

By the way, I'd double-check my assertion about the Mountain Lion purchase personally, but my ISP doesn't let me connect to the App Store for some reason...